# Fetching Wordpress JSON data via URL for an iOS app

Tags: ios, json, wordpress, rest, feed

I'm currently using the following code to pull data from a static JSON file inside my iOS app:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

navigationController.delegate = self;

NSString* jsonFile = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] stringByAppendingString:@"/app.json"];
NSString* jsonString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:jsonFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
@try {
    RootViewController* rootViewController = (RootViewController*)[navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
    rootViewController.feed = [[jsonString JSONValue] objectForKey:@"thefeed"];
    [self.window addSubview:navigationController.view];
}

@catch (NSException * e) { }

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
```

}

It works like I want it to for static data, but I need it to work dynamically via a live url instead. I'm using the Wordpress REST API to kick out the JSON I want over here: http://milknsugar.com/wp-json/posts?filter[posts_per_page]=50&filter[order]=DESC

I've tried several variations of the following without much luck:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
navigationController.delegate = self;

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:MILKNSUGAR_URL]];
NSURLConnection* Connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
if (Connection)
    self.feed = [NSMutableData data];

[self.window addSubview:loadingView];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
```

}

Any advice or suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: Have you implemented the delegate methods for NSURLConnection?

Comment: @jailani yes I have.

Comment: If you want an easy way to get your posts in your app in a way that you can just access objects, then have a look at this sample: https://github.com/evermeer/AlamofireJsonToObjects/blob/master/AlamofireJsonToObjectsTests/WordpressTest.swift

Answer (score 0):

I think this will solve your problem. take a variable

```
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSMutableData *dataReceived;
```

and write this code in wherever you want to send request.

```
NSURLRequest *request=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:MILKNSUGAR_URL]];
NSURLConnection *conn=[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
[conn start];

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {

    if (!_dataReceived) {
        _dataReceived=[[NSMutableData alloc]initWithData:data];
    }else{
        [_dataReceived appendData:data];
    }
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    id result=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:_dataReceived options:kNilOptions error:nil];
    //result will be the parent object of the json what ever you are returning from json. may be array or dictionary.
}
```

i have checked your url. its returning array of dictionaries. the result will be array. use it.